# Excel: Replacing Everything After Word in Other Column

Tags: excel, replace

I have 2 columns in excel like this

**Column1**

hxxp://url.com/something-WORD-/

hxxp://url.com/something-else-WORD2-/

**Column2**

Word

Word2

I would like to search for the word in Column2 in Column1 and if found replace it and everything else after it with nothing so column 3 would look like

**Column3**

hxxp://url.com/something

hxxp://url.com/something-else

Any help is appreciated as I can't find a solution anywhere, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let column 3 have the forumla:

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(B1,A1)-1)`.

If column 2 has the value `Word`

Then column 3 will be

`hxxp://url.com/something-`

You can subtract an extra digit in the forumla if the value in column 2 is always preceded by a dash you want removed as well.

You can wrap this in some `=ISERR` checking as well if you expect that the value in column 2 may not be found.

Comment: Thanks very much Tim, that's perfect and oh so simple!
*smacks self on head for not figuring it out!*